# Automatically place response item into next request (raw --> x-www-form) (POSTMAN)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, api, postman

In POSTMAN, I'm having difficultly finding a way to place an item received from a JIRA Issue response(`JSON`) to the next request. BUT placing this item under (`x-www-form-urlencoded`) as a 'value' in the next request.

I'm including a few screen shots below to give a better visual of what I'm doing. However what I can't seem to figure out is a way to place that item as a value in (x-www.form...) format of the next request from an environment variable standpoing.

**Context:**

I've set up automation tests in POSTMAN which count any failures, save those failures to a variable. At the end of the Collection run, a JIRA REST API request is sent to create an Issue if those `failures > 0`.  Furthermore, if the JIRA request is initiated, it will return the JIRA issue link inside the response. I've used an environment variable to get receive the link under "self".

[image]

So, whats confusing me is that to send a message to Slack through Slacks API, it goes under the format: `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Under this format, there are 3 KEYs needed to successfully send a slack message:

```
 KEY            VALUE
Token       (Authorization)
Channel     (Channel ID)
Text        (The Message)
```

I input all the necessary items in its respected places to send a message.  The message works successfully however it does not include the env variable I set in the prior request in the Collection run.  I hope would be that this would add the Jira issue link to the slack message so I'm able to click the link from there.

[image]

My question is, why isn't the env variable saving the response data and adding it to the next request which is the Slack Message?

Comment: Did you try `{{Link}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use variable in Postman UI, not Postman script (Pre-quest, Test), you need follow the syntax `{{variable_name}}`. In this case, you should use `{{Link}}`, not `Link`